# Intercept and coefficients of Logistic Regression are not precise

Tags: python, pandas, data-modeling, logistic-regression

I recently trained a model with Logistic Regression in Pandas and it worked perfectly. Then I tried the same for another column, but this time I get strange coefficients and if I create a function with them and enter random inputs, I dont get correctly the output.

So, let me explain now more detailed. I first clean my data and I have a column from type integer which will be my target column. For this reason I transform the column so that all cells that have the value 1 become 0 and all other cells (with values greater than 1) become 1. This works perfect and if I check the values (with value_counts()) I get 1.300.000 0-s in the column and about 400.000 1-s. This means respectively that modeling after that I should get more often a 0 as an output.
Then I model the data and get my intercept and the coefficients. I create a function using them, but when I start giving input I always get a 1 as an output. Even if I enter such inputs that should contribute to an output = 0 I still get output of 1. Do I make something wrong? I know that the model has 77% accuracy, but it still should return 0-s :D

P.S I will rename my column for the post to get shorter names and to be easier:

```
acc_data_for_modeling_2.head()
```

The casualt will be the target column. Here it still containts values between 1 and 87.

```
             vehicles   casualt light_cond  Fatal Serious Slight Urban
Accident_Index                          
200501BS00001      1        1      1          0      1      0      1
200501BS00002      1        1      0          0      0      1      1
200501BS00003      2        1      0          0      0      1      1
200501BS00004      1        1      1          0      0      1      1
200501BS00005      1        1      0          0      0      1      1
```

Now I will change this and convert the column to numerical boolean:

```
acc_data_for_modeling_2.casual = np.where(acc_data_for_modeling_2.casualt>1, 1,0)
```

```
acc_data_for_modeling_2["num_of_casualties"].value_counts()
```

This function returns the following which means that we have many more 0-s as output.:

```
0    1367268
1     413211
Name: num_of_casualties, dtype: int64
```

```
acc_data_target_2 = acc_data_for_modeling_2.casualt
acc_data_features_2 = acc_data_for_modeling_2.drop("casualt", axis=1)
```

```
acc_data_features_scaled_2 = scaler.fit_transform(acc_data_features_2)
acc_data_scaled_2 = scaler.fit_transform(acc_data_for_modeling_2)
```

```
features_train_2, features_test_2, target_train_2, target_test_2 = train_test_split(
    acc_data_features_scaled_2, acc_data_target_2, train_size = 0.7, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

```
model_2 = LogisticRegression()
model_2.fit(features_train_2, target_train_2)
```

```
accuracy_2 = model_2.score(features_test_2, target_test_2)
print(accuracy_2)

0.7729806943445963
```

```
model_2.intercept_

array([-0.76128204])
```

```
model_2.coef_

array([[48.99279695, -0.22751056,  0.26471774, -0.37005559, -0.65594413,
        -0.56159163]])
```

After I get the coefficients and the intercept, i create my function to test the model:

```
def more_than_1_casualty(num_of_vehicles, light_cond,accident_severity_Fatal, accident_severity_Serious, 
                         accident_severity_Slight, urban_or_rural_area_Urban):
    power = (-(-0.76128204 + 48.99279695*num_of_vehicles -0.22751056*light_cond
               +0.26471774*accident_severity_Fatal  -0.37005559*accident_severity_Serious 
               -0.65594413*accident_severity_Slight -0.56159163*urban_or_rural_area_Urban))

    result = 1/(1+np.exp(power))

    return result
```

then I enter some inputs and the case below should return more likely an output 0, but...:

```
more_than_1_casualty(1,1,0,0,1,1)
1.0
```

I expect to get output values 0 sometimes and not only 1. I think this model would not be reliable in this form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try experimenting with different regularisation and class_weights... eg `model_2 = LogisticRegression(C=0.001, class_weights='balanced')`

Comment: This worked! I still can not get a 0 value, but now my output is like 0.2/0.3 which is much more acceptable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

yhe term `48.99279695*num_of_vehicles` is dominating in your expression which makes your power variable lower than - 40 as soon as you have more than two cars. If you take the sigmoid of that you get a number extremely close to 1 as `exp(-40) = 4.248354255291589e-18` and python does the rounding to 1.

Comment: Exactly, but I cant understand why this happens. The model has been trained so that the 0 is the more probable output. Is there anything wrong in my code or how can I get output values = 0. If I always get 1, then this model is definitely not reliable.

Comment: Maybe check that the model probbas predicted by the `predict` method and the proba predicted by your functions are the same.

Comment: most of the observations in the dataset do have indeed 2-3 cars involved, but there is only 1 casualty in the accident which should mean for us that the value in the data set for modelling should be 0. I really don't get why the number of vehicles get such a high coefficient and thus make my model invalid or imprecise.

Comment: How do i do this with the predict method?